# csh doesn't recognize command with command line options beginning with --

Tags: bash, csh

I have an rsync command in my csh script like this:

```
#! /bin/csh -f
set source_dir = "blahDir/blahBlahDir"
set dest_dir   = "foo/anotherFoo"
rsync -av --exclude=*.csv ${source_dir} ${dest_dir}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
rsync: No match.
```

If I remove the `--exclude` option it works. I wrote the equivalent script in bash and that works as expected

```
#/bin/bash -f 
source_dir="blahDir/blahBlahDir"
dest_dir="foo/anotherFoo"
rsync -av --exclude=*.csv ${source_dir} ${dest_dir}
```

The problem is that this has to be done in csh only. Any ideas on how I can get his to work?

Comment: Do you happen to have a `.csv` file in the directory where your run the command from?

Comment: I have a .csv file in my source_dir directory of the rsync command which I want to exclude from the transfer.

Comment: But you do not have one in your command dir ? I was thinking maybe the wildcard is expanded before the rsync command is run

Comment: No, I don't have a *.csv in my command dir, But maybe you are right, I will try putting a dummy csv in my command dir. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `csh` is trying to *expand* `--exclude=*.csv` into a filename, and complaining because it cannot find a file matching that pattern.

You can get around this by enclosing the option in quotes:

```
rsynv -rv '--exclude=*.csv' ...
```

or escaping the asterisk:

```
rsynv -rv --exclude=\*.csv ...
```

This is a consequence of the way `csh` and `bash` differ in their default treatment of arguments with wildcards that don't match a file. `csh` will complain while `bash` will simply leave it alone.

You may *think* `bash` has chosen the better way but that's not necessarily so, as shown in the following transcript where you have a file matching the argument:

```
pax> touch -- '--file=xyzzy.csv' ; ls -- *.csv
--file=xyzzy.csv

pax> echo --file=*.csv
--file=xyzzy.csv
```

You can see there that the `bash` shell *expands* the argument rather than giving it to the program as is. Both sides have their pros and cons.

Comment: I tried the first solution and it worked, a newbie issue after all. Thanks a lot

Comment: Note that `bash` works because an unmatched pattern is treated as a literal string rather than an error.